# error _InternalLinkedHashMap in the flutter for http

Tags: flutter, http, dart, exception, rest

I run this set of code in the flutter, but the runtime shows the error in the image

[image]

```
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

class ServisApi {
  final client = http.Client();

  Future<ModelSpescal> PokomanSpeciesServisApli(int id) async {
    final Url = Uri.https('pokeapi.co', '/api/v2/pokemon-species/$id/');
    print('pokospikal' '  ' '${Url}');
    final response1 =
        await client.get(Url).then((value) => json.decode(value.body));
    print((response1.toString().isNotEmpty));
    final ResponsFromjson = ModelSpescal(test: response1);

    return ResponsFromjson;
  }
}

class ModelSpescal {
  final String test;
  ModelSpescal({required this.test});

  factory ModelSpescal.Fromjson(Map<String, dynamic> jsonTest) {
    return ModelSpescal(test: jsonTest['name']);
  }
}


main() {
  print(ServisApi().PokomanSpeciesServisApli(320));
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may be due to the type casting problem.  Since you are using `async` and `await` you can simplify the code like below.

```
Future<ModelSpescal> PokomanSpeciesServisApli(int id) async {
    // Other codes
    final response = await http.get(Url);
    final Map<String, dynamic> response1 = json.decode(response.body);
    final ResponsFromjson = ModelSpescal.Fromjson(response1);
    return ResponsFromjson;
}
```

Comment: I did what you said, but ''test: response1'' gets an error, which must be of type string
error reponse1===>(( The argument type 'Map<String, dynamic>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String'))
Unfortunately the problem was not solved

Comment: check my updated answer. Replace `ModelSpescal` with `ModelSpescal.Fromjson`. That's my mistake :/